# Is it possible to name macro (`\newcommand`) parameters and do math with them?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I'm new to creating commands in LaTeX, and I would like to do something like adding a more helpful name inside my command, as I do calculations with it; while also doing some math with said parameter. Here's an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\gogrid}[1][1]{
  % Here are some of my attempts:

  % \def\size{#1 / 19}
  \newlength{\size}
  \setlength{\size}{#1 / 19}
  % Maybe I need to specify the type of the `#1` parameter?

  \draw[step=#1 / 19] (-#1, -#1) grid (#1,#1);
  \draw[line width=1] (-#1, #1) -- (#1 + 0.015, #1); % chktex 8
  \draw[line width=1] (#1, -#1) -- (#1, #1); % chktex 8
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \gogrid
        % \draw(-5,-5) grid (5,5);
        \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
        \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{\label{my_grid}A grid with two points!}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is this possible in LaTeX? I use this sort of thing a lot in regular programming languages to make things more readable. (Also, on a sidenote, if anyone has a book or website reference with this sort of thing, I would really appreciate it.)

Comment: move `\newlength{\size}` out of the macro, you do not want to allocate a new register every time the macro is used (they are a finite resource) just allocate it once. numbered parameters are not so bad. for calculations you can do `\setlength{\size}{\dimexpr #1 / 19}`

Comment: See [`namedef`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/namedef)

Comment: If you're doing this in a `tikzpicture`, you can let PGF do it. Not as fast as `\dimexpr`, but less faff. If you just get rid of the `\newlength` and `\setlength` lines, you get your grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything will be working in your example, if you could define a suitable unit for the arg `#1` in the `\setlength` command, while using the proper syntax for dimension calculation inside TikZ as well. You could omit the units for the TikZ drawing but not for the dimension calculation. So you must use `\setlength{\size}{\dimexpr#1cm/19\relax}`.

In TikZ, if the unit of the coordinates are omitted, then `cm` are assumed.  For line width, `pt` will be used.

As mentioned in the comments, the `\newlength{\size}` should be placed out of the command definition, because you don't need to redefine the same new length every time.

Here are two examples using your code to generate the grid. I printed out the value of the `\size` as a node below the center point and set the center point radius equal to the `\size` length, just to show that the dimension calculations actually worked. The center points occupy 4 blocks exactly.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\size}
\newcommand{\gogrid}[1][1]{
  \setlength{\size}{\dimexpr#1cm/19\relax}

  \draw[step=\size] (-#1, -#1) grid (#1,#1);
  \draw[red,line width=1] (-#1, #1) -- (\dimexpr#1cm+1cm , #1); 
  \draw[blue,line width=1] (#1, -#1) -- (#1, #1);
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \gogrid
        \filldraw (0,0) circle [radius=1.49751pt] node[below] {\the\size};
        \filldraw (1,1) circle[radius=1.49751pt];
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{A grid with two points!}\label{my_grid1}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \gogrid[5]
        \filldraw (0,0) circle [radius=7.48756pt] node[below=0.5cm] {\the\size};
        \filldraw (5,5) circle[radius=3pt];
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Another grid with two points!}\label{my_grid2}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> Output:

[image: default size = 1]
[image: size = 5]

Comment: Aside from printing out `\size`, you never once use `\size` in the code. The actual grid drawing makes no use of it. It works perfectly well if you simply remove that definition, as my answer shows.

Comment: @cfr You are right, I just to want show how to make the `\setlength` command work. Probably OP want replace the `step=#1/19` with `step=\size`.

Comment: @cfr I want to explain to OP that his initial attempt will work if he use the correct syntax. However, yes, as you said,  he even won't need to define the `\size`.

Comment: But you say `You could omit the units for tikz drawing but not for dimension calculation.` If you're using `pgfmath`, you can omit the units for dimension calculations. Unless you mean only dimension calculations which use `\dimexpr`. But you don't need that in the drawing code either. The only advantage is speed.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I should be more clear. I want express that unit can not be omitted when use `\dimexpr`

Comment: If you approve the edits I've made, I think your answer is all I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this inside `tikzpicture`s, you can just let `pgfmath` handle the calculations. Simply deleting the `\newlength...` and `\setlength...` lines works.

```
\newcommand{\gogrid}[1][1]{%
  \draw[step=#1 / 19] (-#1, -#1) grid (#1,#1);
  \draw[line width=1] (-#1, #1) -- (#1 + 0.015, #1); % chktex 8
  \draw[line width=1] (#1, -#1) -- (#1, #1); % chktex 8
}
```

enables `\gogrid[<number or length>]` inside `tikzpicture`s.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gogrid[10mm]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gogrid[5]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, for this specific usage, you could just use `grid` directly.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=2/19]  (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: three grids]

Note that if you don't specify units, PGF will use the current unit in most cases. By default, that is 1cm on each axis, but the value is customisable and may be set independently for horizontal and vertical, if required.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\gogrid}[1][1]{%
  \draw[step=#1 / 19] (-#1, -#1) grid (#1,#1);
  \draw[line width=1] (-#1, #1) -- (#1 + 0.015, #1); % chktex 8
  \draw[line width=1] (#1, -#1) -- (#1, #1); % chktex 8
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gogrid[10mm]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \gogrid[5]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=2/19]  (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

If you want to use a macro rather than a parameter in the calculations for clarity, I'd make use of `pgfkeys` if you're doing this in a `tikzpicture`. There are various ways of setting this up but, if you only want to specify size (and don't want to tweak the grid with any other options), I'd try something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  go grid/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      go grid/.cd,
      size=#1,
    }%
    \draw [step=\gogridsize/19] (-\gogridsize, -\gogridsize) grid (\gogridsize,\gogridsize);
    \draw[line width=1] (-\gogridsize, \gogridsize) -- (\gogridsize + 0.015, \gogridsize); % chktex 8
    \draw[line width=1] (\gogridsize, -\gogridsize) -- (\gogridsize, \gogridsize); % chktex 8
  },
  go grid/.default=10mm,
  go grid/.cd,
  size/.store in=\gogridsize,
  size/.initial=1cm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[go grid]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[go grid=5]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[go grid=20mm]
  \filldraw[black](0,0)circle[radius=3pt];
  \filldraw[black](1,1)circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want multiple grids per picture, you could use a `pic` or, as you did initially, just define a command.

```
\newcommand{\gogrid}[1][1]{%
  \tikzset{go grid/size=#1,go grid}%
}
```

If you want to specify other aspects of the grids, there are again different approaches. I'd probably try something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708415/ addaswyd o gwestiwn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708410/
  go grid/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  go grid/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      go grid/.cd,
      #1,
    }%
    \begin{scope}[draw=\gogridcolour]
      \draw [step=\gogridsize/19] (-\gogridsize, -\gogridsize) grid (\gogridsize,\gogridsize);
      \draw[line width=1] (-\gogridsize, \gogridsize) -- (\gogridsize + 0.015, \gogridsize); % chktex 8
      \draw[line width=1] (\gogridsize, -\gogridsize) -- (\gogridsize, \gogridsize); % chktex 8
    \end{scope}
    \edef\tempa{}\edef\tempb{\gogridstonesat}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \else
      \foreach \i in \gogridstonesat \filldraw[\gogridstones]\i circle [radius=\gogridstonesize];
    \fi
  },
  go grid/.default={size=10mm},
  go grid/.cd,
  grid/.store in=\gogridcolour,
  grid=black,
  size/.store in=\gogridsize,
  size=1cm,
  stone size/.store in=\gogridstonesize,
  stone size=3pt,
  stones/.store in=\gogridstones,
  stones=black,
  stones at/.store in=\gogridstonesat,
  stones at={},
}
\NewDocumentCommand \gogrid { O{} }
{%
  \tikz[go grid={#1}]{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[go grid={grid=blue,stones at={(0,0),(1,1)},stones=red}]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[go grid={size=5,stones at={(0,0),(1,1)}}]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[go grid={size=20mm,grid=green,stones at={(0,0),(1,1)},stone size=4pt}]
  \node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {Green Go Grid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\gogrid
\gogrid[size=2.5cm,grid=orange,stones at={(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1)},stone size=2.5pt,stones=blue]
\end{document}
```

[image: Various customised go grids]

Comment: I know I can perform the calculations inside stuff, but that's not very readable overall. This doesn't answer anything. My code example even had one of these calculations already!

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Indeed, but your code example didn't actually compile. So it was not obvious (to me) that you knew it would work without the additional lines. If the point is just to use names rather than parameters for clarity, why not just use `.store` and `pgfkeys`? (Or just use the key directly, but I always find that less convenient.)

Comment: I probably wouldn't choose `.store` or `pgfkeys` because I didn't even know they existed. Adding them as possible methods to an answer would help.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro See edit. Obviously likely to be a somewhat silly example: I doubt you really want multicoloured diagrams or you'd have drawn them, but you might want to vary some feature or other either here or elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough edit!